# argocd ssl certificate with google managed certificates

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, argocd

So, I have an Argocd installation where I am using [Google Managed Certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) to use SSL.

As per [Argocd Ingress Documentation](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/ingress/) there is no official way defined to do this.
To use the Google Managed Certificates I have created the following manifest files.

**gcp-managed.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: gcp-managed
spec:
  domains:
    - subdomain.env.domain.com
```

**argocd-ingress-1.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-ingress-1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: argocd-static-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: gcp-managed
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: argocd-service
    servicePort: 80
```

**argocd-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: argocd-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

Also, since we are using cloudflare I have added the Static-IP to an `A record` for subdomain.env.domain.com
Now, the Google Managed Certificate gives me (on ,`kubectl describe managedcertificate gcp-managed -n argocd`)

```
Status:
  Certificate Name:    certificate-unique-id
  Certificate Status:  Provisioning
  Domain Status:
    Domain:  subdomain.env.domain.com
    Status:  FailedNotVisible
```

And the health checks for the argocd-server are failing which is leading to the above issue of `FailedNotVisible`, since unless the health checks are passed GKE loadbalancers don't direct the traffic.

So, what am I doing wrong ? \ What else can I do to make this work.
Using third party apps like [Ambassador Edge Stack](https://www.getambassador.io/) or any other is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the trick was to use the argocd [command reference](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/commands/argocd/#options) `--insecure` flag.
Creating a custom argocd service, turning off proxy in Cloudflare and using an ingress which was using the managed certificate.

`development-argocd-static-ip` = a static IP which is global in nature
`argocd-server, gcp-managed, argocd-service, argocd-ingress` all are in the same namespace

**argocd-server.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-server
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            weight: 100
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            weight: 5
      containers:
      - command:
        - argocd-server
        - --insecure    # added this
        - --staticassets
        - /shared/app
        image: quay.io/argoproj/argocd:v2.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz?full=true
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 30
        name: argocd-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 8083
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 30
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - all
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/config/ssh
          name: ssh-known-hosts
        - mountPath: /app/config/tls
          name: tls-certs
        - mountPath: /app/config/server/tls
          name: argocd-repo-server-tls
      serviceAccountName: argocd-server
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: static-files
      - configMap:
          name: argocd-ssh-known-hosts-cm
        name: ssh-known-hosts
      - configMap:
          name: argocd-tls-certs-cm
        name: tls-certs
      - name: argocd-repo-server-tls
        secret:
          items:
          - key: tls.crt
            path: tls.crt
          - key: tls.key
            path: tls.key
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          optional: true
          secretName: argocd-repo-server-tls
```

**gcp-managed.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: gcp-managed
spec:
  domains:
    - subdomain.env.domain.com
```

**argocd-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: argocd-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

**argocd-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: development-argocd-static-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: gcp-managed
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: argocd-service
              servicePort: 80
```

On the following command,
`kubectl describe managedcertificate gcp-managed -n argocd`

```
Status:
  Certificate Name:    certificate-unique-id
  Certificate Status:  Active
  Domain Status:
    Domain:     subdomain.env.domain.com
    Status:     Active
```